# Regex for port numbers in Android?

Tags: android, regex

Consider a regex for testing port numbers.

```
(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})
```

This is not valid in Android.

Any idea what a port number regex should look like in Android?

Comment: Define not valid?  Doesn't compile, doesn't match what you want it to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, regex isn't that great for numerical validation.  I'd recommend using `Integer.parseInt` on a matched group and then check that to see if it's less than 65536.

Comment: Agreed.  I tried to validate an integer range for a tokenizer with regex once and got super frustrated trying to get it right.  Match [0-9]+ and then get it into a number format.

Answer (score 2):

`"(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d{2}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3})"` works on [a Java Regex test page](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) assuming that you are writing Java code.  You probably have to escape the backslashes for the Java string literal to work.  However, this expression does not thing that zero is a valid port number.

Answer (score -1):

It is old one, but in case someone is wondering how to use tryparse, a mentioned by one of developers:

```
int portNumber;
if (int.TryParse(inputPortValue, out portNumber)
    && portNumber >= 256
    && portNumber <= 0){
     error = "Invalid Port: " + inputPortValue
     ". Please verify.";
     return false;
     }
```

Comment: It is in C# actually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294878/how-the-int-tryparse-actually-works Somehow missed it is Android question or probably was edited later.