# How the int.TryParse actually works

Tags: c#

I've looked for `int.TryParse` method implementation, how does it work actually, but I haven't found. I have to know, about a `string`, whether it's a numeric value, but I don't want to convert it at the this time.

So I need only the `bool` result from `int.TryParse`. So the questions are:

1. Is there any function which can provide only the `bool` result,

and

2. I'd like to know, how the `int.TryParse` actually works (is there a `try ... catch` inside or iterates through the characters of input `string`)?

Comment: 1. No, there isn't. You could use `Convert.ToInt32()`, but it will throw an exception, if the string cannot be parsed.  2. It will have to iterate through the string, but it probably won't catch any exception, since it's faster than catching the exception from `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: You could use regex ^\d+$.  Or evaluate each char for IsDigit.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If you only need the `bool` result, just use the return value and ignore the `out` parameter.

```
bool successfullyParsed = int.TryParse(str, out ignoreMe);
if (successfullyParsed){
    // ...
}
```

**Edit**: Meanwhile you can also have a look at the [original source code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx):

[`System.Int32.TryParse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,325507e509229dbc,references)

---

If i want to know how something is actually implemented, i'm using [**`ILSpy`**](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile the .NET-code.

This is the result:

```
// int
/// <summary>Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation succeeded.</summary>
/// <returns>true if s was converted successfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
/// <param name="s">A string containing a number to convert. </param>
/// <param name="result">When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null, is not of the correct format, or represents a number less than <see cref="F:System.Int32.MinValue"></see> or greater than <see cref="F:System.Int32.MaxValue"></see>. This parameter is passed uninitialized. </param>
/// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
public static bool TryParse(string s, out int result)
{
    return Number.TryParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out result);
}


// System.Number
internal unsafe static bool TryParseInt32(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info, out int result)
{
    byte* stackBuffer = stackalloc byte[1 * 114 / 1];
    Number.NumberBuffer numberBuffer = new Number.NumberBuffer(stackBuffer);
    result = 0;
    if (!Number.TryStringToNumber(s, style, ref numberBuffer, info, false))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        if (!Number.HexNumberToInt32(ref numberBuffer, ref result))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Number.NumberToInt32(ref numberBuffer, ref result))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And no, i cannot see any `Try-Catchs` on the road:

```
// System.Number
private unsafe static bool TryStringToNumber(string str, NumberStyles options, ref Number.NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo numfmt, bool parseDecimal)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    fixed (char* ptr = str)
    {
        char* ptr2 = ptr;
        if (!Number.ParseNumber(ref ptr2, options, ref number, numfmt, parseDecimal) || ((ptr2 - ptr / 2) / 2 < str.Length && !Number.TrailingZeros(str, (ptr2 - ptr / 2) / 2)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// System.Number
private unsafe static bool ParseNumber(ref char* str, NumberStyles options, ref Number.NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo numfmt, bool parseDecimal)
{
    number.scale = 0;
    number.sign = false;
    string text = null;
    string text2 = null;
    string str2 = null;
    string str3 = null;
    bool flag = false;
    string str4;
    string str5;
    if ((options & NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        text = numfmt.CurrencySymbol;
        if (numfmt.ansiCurrencySymbol != null)
        {
            text2 = numfmt.ansiCurrencySymbol;
        }
        str2 = numfmt.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        str3 = numfmt.NumberGroupSeparator;
        str4 = numfmt.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
        str5 = numfmt.CurrencyGroupSeparator;
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        str4 = numfmt.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        str5 = numfmt.NumberGroupSeparator;
    }
    int num = 0;
    char* ptr = str;
    char c = *ptr;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!Number.IsWhite(c) || (options & NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite) == NumberStyles.None || ((num & 1) != 0 && ((num & 1) == 0 || ((num & 32) == 0 && numfmt.numberNegativePattern != 2))))
        {
            bool flag2;
            char* ptr2;
            if ((flag2 = ((options & NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign) != NumberStyles.None && (num & 1) == 0)) && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.positiveSign)) != null)
            {
                num |= 1;
                ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (flag2 && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.negativeSign)) != null)
                {
                    num |= 1;
                    number.sign = true;
                    ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c == '(' && (options & NumberStyles.AllowParentheses) != NumberStyles.None && (num & 1) == 0)
                    {
                        num |= 3;
                        number.sign = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((text == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text)) == null) && (text2 == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text2)) == null))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        num |= 32;
                        text = null;
                        text2 = null;
                        ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
    }
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || ((options & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None && ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'))))
        {
            num |= 4;
            if (c != '0' || (num & 8) != 0)
            {
                if (num2 < 50)
                {
                    number.digits[(IntPtr)(num2++)] = c;
                    if (c != '0' || parseDecimal)
                    {
                        num3 = num2;
                    }
                }
                if ((num & 16) == 0)
                {
                    number.scale++;
                }
                num |= 8;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((num & 16) != 0)
                {
                    number.scale--;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char* ptr2;
            if ((options & NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint) != NumberStyles.None && (num & 16) == 0 && ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str4)) != null || (flag && (num & 32) == 0 && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str2)) != null)))
            {
                num |= 16;
                ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((options & NumberStyles.AllowThousands) == NumberStyles.None || (num & 4) == 0 || (num & 16) != 0 || ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str5)) == null && (!flag || (num & 32) != 0 || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, str3)) == null)))
                {
                    break;
                }
                ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
            }
        }
        c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
    }
    bool flag3 = false;
    number.precision = num3;
    number.digits[(IntPtr)num3] = '\0';
    if ((num & 4) != 0)
    {
        if ((c == 'E' || c == 'e') && (options & NumberStyles.AllowExponent) != NumberStyles.None)
        {
            char* ptr3 = ptr;
            c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
            char* ptr2;
            if ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.positiveSign)) != null)
            {
                c = *(ptr = ptr2);
            }
            else
            {
                if ((ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.negativeSign)) != null)
                {
                    c = *(ptr = ptr2);
                    flag3 = true;
                }
            }
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                int num4 = 0;
                do
                {
                    num4 = num4 * 10 + (int)(c - '0');
                    c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
                    if (num4 > 1000)
                    {
                        num4 = 9999;
                        while (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                        {
                            c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
                if (flag3)
                {
                    num4 = -num4;
                }
                number.scale += num4;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr = ptr3;
                c = *ptr;
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            if (!Number.IsWhite(c) || (options & NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite) == NumberStyles.None)
            {
                bool flag2;
                char* ptr2;
                if ((flag2 = ((options & NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign) != NumberStyles.None && (num & 1) == 0)) && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.positiveSign)) != null)
                {
                    num |= 1;
                    ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (flag2 && (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, numfmt.negativeSign)) != null)
                    {
                        num |= 1;
                        number.sign = true;
                        ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (c == ')' && (num & 2) != 0)
                        {
                            num &= -3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((text == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text)) == null) && (text2 == null || (ptr2 = Number.MatchChars(ptr, text2)) == null))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            text = null;
                            text2 = null;
                            ptr = ptr2 - (IntPtr)2 / 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            c = *(ptr += (IntPtr)2 / 2);
        }
        if ((num & 2) == 0)
        {
            if ((num & 8) == 0)
            {
                if (!parseDecimal)
                {
                    number.scale = 0;
                }
                if ((num & 16) == 0)
                {
                    number.sign = false;
                }
            }
            str = ptr;
            return true;
        }
    }
    str = ptr;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's more complex then I thaught :) Thank you!

Comment: Very informational, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

We can now in C# 7.0 and above write this:

```
if (int.TryParse(inputString, out _))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is not to answer the question.

Comment: what does out do ?

Comment: @mrid It specifies that a variable in the calling scope is being given to the method scope with write access. E.g. If a variable `int someInt` is passed to `int.TryParse` like `int.TryParse(out someInt)`, `int.TryParse` may place its output in `someInt`, even though it would normally be out of scope.

Comment: @themefield - it answers this question right in the body of the post: " So the questions are: 1) Is there any function which can provide only the bool result".

Answer (score 24):

TryParse is the best way for parse or validate in single line:

```
int nNumber = int.TryParse("InputString", out nNumber) ? nNumber : 1;
```

Short description:

1. nNumber will initialize with zero,
2. int.TryParse() try parse "InputString" and validate it, if succeed set into nNumber.
3. short if ?: checking int.TryParse() result, that return nNumber or 1 as default value.

Comment: `cannot use local variable 'nCurPage' before it is declared`

Comment: dear devin-burke, you right, but it work. I using it multiple time, without any error or warning ...

Comment: To avoid compiler error one can write this one-liner as:
`var nNumber = int.TryParse("InputString", out var result) ? result : 1;`, but unlike other comments are saying orginal answer complies on my device.

Answer (score 22):

Just because `int.TryParse` gives you the value doesn't mean you need to keep it; you can quite happily do this:

```
int temp;
if (int.TryParse(inputString, out temp))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

You can ignore `temp` entirely if you don't need it. If you do need it, then hey, it's waiting for you when you want it.

As for the internals, as far as I remember it attempts to read the raw bytes of the string as an int and tests whether the result is valid, or something; it's not as simple as iterating through looking for non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 9):

Regex is compiled so for speed create it once and reuse it.
The new takes longer than the IsMatch.
This only checks for all digits.
It does not check for range.
If you need to test range then TryParse is the way to go.

```
private static Regex regexInt = new Regex("^\\d+$");
static bool CheckReg(string value)
{
    return regexInt.IsMatch(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this simple program to understand `int.TryParse`

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main()
    {
        string str = "7788";
        int num1;
        bool n = int.TryParse(str, out num1);
        Console.WriteLine(num1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output is : 7788