# What is the best workaround for the lack of TryParse() when targeting WindowsCE?

Tags: c#, casting, windows-ce, tryparse, target-platform

In moving some code over from my test project to the "real" project, which targets Windows CE, some code got embarrassed and turned red in the IDE, namely "TryParse()".

For the lack of ... a horseshoe, the battle was lost; hopefully, the lack of TryParse() will not cause a healthcare.gov-like eCatastrophe; nevertheless is there a better way to rewrite a TryParse() for a TryParseless parser than:

```
int recCount = 0;
string s = "42";
try {
    recCount = Int32.Parse(s);      
}
catch {
    MessageBox.Show("That was not an int! Consider this a lint-like hint!");
}
```

?

Comment: If `s` is a string, that will never *succeed*.  In fact, it won't even *compile* because the compiler can be 100% sure it will never succeed.

Comment: True; I changed it, but my question remains the same: is there a less kludgy way of accomplishing this, given the limitations of WindowsCE target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `s` is a string value, you can't cast it to `int`. If `int.TryParse` is not available then you can create your own method which would return a bool . Something like:

```
public static class MyIntConversion
{
    public static bool MyTryParse(object parameter, out int value)
    {
        value = 0;
        try
        {
            value = Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and then to use it:

```
int temp;
if (!MyIntConversion.MyTryParse("123", out temp))
{
     MessageBox.Show("That was not an int! Consider this a lint-like hint!");
}
```

<strike>[`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) internally uses `try-catch` to do parsing and is implemented in similar manner.</strike>

Comment: Per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294878/how-the-int-tryparse-actually-works, I don't think `int.TryParse` uses `try-catch`. I'd still write it that way if it wasn't available.

Comment: @JoelRondeau, I am actually going through the source, but yes it appears `int.TryParse` doesn't uses exception handling

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool TryParseInt32( this string str, out int result )
{
    result = default(int);

    try
    {
        result = Int32.Parse( str );
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

usage:

```
int result;
string str = "1234";

if( str.TryParseInt32( out result ) )
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `s` is a string. If so, your code won't work. The following code should though:

```
int recCount = 0;
try {
    recCount = Int32.Parse(s);      
}
catch {
    MessageBox.Show("That was not an int! Consider this a lint-like hint!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I'm still wondering if there's a better option than a kludgy try/catch, though...

Comment: @ClayShannon - None that I know of :(

Comment: @ClayShannon there isn't... It's the obvious choice. Habib's answer likely has the actual body of tryparse in it. You could follow his lead and define your own function to make it so you don't have try-catch's all over the place but there is no way to get around using a try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.

```
public bool IsNumber(string text)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");
    bool onlyNumbers = reg.IsMatch(text);
    return onlyNumbers;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution; thanks; I upticked it, but normally when I see Regex, I run for the hills as if I had just come upon a swaying cobra in the middle of the path.

Comment: You have a problem.  It can be solved with a RegEx.  Now you have two problems.