# String is considered 'bool' after TryParse to int

Tags: c#, type-conversion, tryparse

I'm trying to convert a text input into an `int` that I can multiply and display the product, but whenever I try to parse the textbox contents as int, I get the *"cannot convert bool to int"* error message. Code is as follows:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Int1;
    int Int2;
    int Product;
    string Text1;
    string Text2;
    Text2 = textBox2.Text;
    Text1 = textBox1.Text;
    Int1 = int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1);
    Int2 = int.TryParse(Text2, out Int2);
    Product = Int1 * Int2;
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(Product);
}
```

Don't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `TryParse` returns a `bool` the result is in the parameter with `out`, to solve you can remove the attribution.

```
int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1);
int.TryParse(Text2, out Int2);
Product = Int1 * Int2;
```

If you using `TryParse` you should use in a `if` to check if everything goes with success.

```
if(int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1) &&  int.TryParse(Text2, out Int2))
{        
    Product = Int1 * Int2;
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(Product);
}
```

If you don't need this behavior, you should consider using `Parse`, because it returns the parsed value.

```
Int1 = int.Parse(Text1);
Int2 = int.Parse(Text2);
Product = Int1 * Int2;
```

Comment: It says I can accept in 7 minutes - does this restriction ever go away?

Comment: No, will the restriction as a whole disappear after a set amount of reputation? (will I be able to accept answers without a time limit at some point later in time)

Comment: @AB will never go away [see this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question)

Answer (score 2):

TryParse returns boolean, which tells you if the parse has succeeded or not. Try

```
int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1);
int.TryParse(Text2, out Int2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is natural. TryParse returns boolean. **out** parameter is the result of TryParse. Check this post: [How the int.TryParse actually works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294878/how-the-int-tryparse-actually-works)

Answer (score 1):

TryParse returns true or false based on its successful or unsuccessful attempt. if you are sure user enters number only, you can use

```
Int1=int.Parse(textBox1.Text)
Int2=int.Parse( textBox2.Text)
```

Comment: It's `Parse` not `pars`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, yes, type error, tnx noticed me. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse()` returns `bool`, and `out` parameter will already have parsed value `Int1` and `Int2` if parsing was successful you have to do like this:

```
if(!int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1))
{
// show validation message
return;
}
if(!int.TryParse(Text2, out Int2))
{
// value not valid int
return;
}
```

`TryParse()` is used when we want to control program flow, you have to handle it using `if` block other wise on invalid input your program will throw exception

> > Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assigning the result of int.TryParse to your int. It cant because the return value is a bool indicating if the parsing worked.

```
Int1 = int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1);
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Int1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the return value of `TryParse` to decide whether the parsing went successfully or not. It returns `bool` to indicate that the text has been converted to `int`, so you should change your code as follows:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int Int1;
    int Int2;
    int Product;
    string Text1;
    string Text2;
    Text2 = textBox2.Text;
    Text1 = textBox1.Text;
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    if( int.TryParse(Text1, out Int1) && int.TryParse(Text2, out Int2)) {
        Product = Int1 * Int2;
        listBox1.Items.Add(Product);
    } else {
        listBox1.Items.Add("<incorrect input>");
    }
}
```

When the return value of one of `TryParse` calls is `false`, the product is not computed, and an error message "" is added to `listBox1` instead of a product.