# Best practice for TryGet method style

Tags: c#, methods, exception

I have an method for enums that looks like this:

```
public static TEnum GetEnumByStringValue<TEnum>(string value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
{
  if(!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enumerated type.");
  }

  Type type = typeof(TEnum);
  FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields();
  foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
  {
    StringValue[] stringValues = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValue), false) as StringValue[];
    if (stringValues != null)
    {
      foreach (StringValue stringValue in stringValues)
      {
        if (stringValue.Value.Equals(value))
        {
          return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), fieldInfo.Name);
        }
      }
    }

  }
  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Value was not found in enum's string values.");
}
```

I'd like to implement a `TryGetEnumByStringValue`, that returns true or false instead of throwing an exception similar to the concept of `int.Parse` and `int.TryParse`. The way I see it, in my new method I could just call my other one, catch the exceptions (if any) and return accordingly, or I could refactor the existing one to return `bool` and again in my new method simply call the existing one and throw an exception if it returns false.

If I go with option 2 I lose exact exception details, and if I go with option 1 the exceptions are still thrown (I've always been taught exceptions are slow).

I could also refactor the existing one to take a `bool` indicating whether to throw exceptions or not, but that doesn't quite sit right with me.

Is there a pearl of wisdom I've missed for this sort of method style or pattern?

Comment: I'd simply use the method that you already have, no need to copy the entire logic, just re-use it

Comment: Please check the following link as example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294878/how-the-int-tryparse-actually-works) `int` also reuses it.

Comment: Your idea of passing a bool to indicate if it should throw could be applied to a private method and then your public methods would call that with the appropriate bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a method that throws, then it's easy to make a `Try...` variant of it using ... suprise! `try/catch`:

```
public bool TryReturnSomething(..., out SomeType result) // ... - parameters
{
    try
    {
        result = ReturnSomething();
        return true;
    }
    catch(SomeException1 e) { } // catch all expected exception types
    catch(SomeException2 e) { }

    return false;
}
```

Looking into [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=tryparse) you will discover that Microsoft is indeed using this kind of *pattern*. They have an internal method which is called with *validated* parameters. And validation is done individually by `Try...` and a normal variant. See e.g. [double.Parse()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,dbae9a94b8fcd241,references) and [double.TryParse()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,ea594ef6586a329e,references). The first one will `throw` for invalid input and the other will return `false`.

So you can create a private method which you call from both method variants. This private method should not validate anything (may raise an exception). Call this method in both public variants, which both validate parameters. (`Try..` returns `false` and the other throws.)

Comment: But please take into account that normally you would use the TryGet pattern for performance issues so you would never throw an exception within this method, because this would slow down the execution of the method dramatically. See the [Microsoft design guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance) here for more information - it is called Try-Parse pattern here.

Comment: Note that you will need to either assign `result` before the `try` or after the last `catch`, since `out` parameters *must* be assigned some value by the method. Usually if the "success" path assignment fails, the value is set to the default for the type:  `result = default(SomeType);`

Comment: The second paragraph is kind of misleading, "this kind of pattern" sounds like it means the pattern just discussed, always throwing and then in the Try variant catching.  But that is not what's done.  I suggest replacing "Microsoft is indeed using this kind of pattern" by "Microsoft has developed a reusable pattern, as follows"