# Trying to understand TryParse(). but don't understand the parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand `int.TryParse` to check if the user inputted the correct thing (in this case an int) but unsure what to type in after `out`.

```
Console.WriteLine("write a number into the console");

int thisnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // this line is converting user inputs string into a int number.
if (!int.TryParse(thisnumber, out )) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is a integer");
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse

Comment: Always check the documentation; there are usually examples of how to use it. However, since you are using `Convert.ToInt32` first, `thisnumber` is already an integer and you do not need to *also* use `TryParse`. (And you'll also get an exception if the input is not something that `Convert.ToInt32` can handle). You should only use one of them.

Comment: It's better to use int.TryParse than convert.ToInt32, because a format exception will be raised if the input can't be converted to a int. 

when using the int.TryParse, you need to specify the type that you want to parse,ie,  you are trying to see if the input is an int.
variable of type int is required, this will hold the value of the parsing.

if (!int.TryParse(input, out int result ))

 {
  Console.WriteLine("Not an integer");
 }
 else
 {
  Console.WriteLine("this is a integer");
 }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How the int.TryParse actually works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294878/how-the-int-tryparse-actually-works)

Answer (score 1):

Check if input is a number like this,

```
Console.WriteLine("wrtie a number into the console");
int thisnumber;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out thisnumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"this is an integer : {thisnumber}");
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the number to the writeline