# How to make String empty to converted textbox in c#

Tags: c#, null, textbox, integer, is-empty

[Here is the form i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MqWy.png)

When I enter an empty value in the textbox I meet exception unhandled page. I want to show an error messagebox when user enter an empty value to the textbox how can I do that ?

```
namespace Random_çalışması
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int number;
        int answer;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

            
            number = rnd.Next(1, 101);

            label1.Text = number.ToString();

            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            answer = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            if(answer == number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the page", "Welcome!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Icorrect entrance", "You can not acces to the page", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Icorrect entrance", "You can not acces to the page", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the empty test at the beginning of the method:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ( textBox1.Text == "" )
  {
    MessageBox.Show(...);
    return;
  }
  answer = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
  ...
}
```

You can also use `int.TryParse()` instead of `Convert` to better catch conversion errors:.

[How the int.TryParse actually works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294878/how-the-int-tryparse-actually-works/15295019)

You can also simply set the button disable by default instead and add this handler on the `TextChanged` event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  button.Enable = textBox1.Text != "";
}
```

And also do the `int.TryParse` here instead too:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  button.Enable = textBox1.Text != "" && int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out _);
}
```

Hence the button is enabled only if not empty and convertible and you have a consistent UX.

Now the button click handler is:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  answer = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
  if ( answer == number )
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the page", "Welcome!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  else
    MessageBox.Show("Icorrect entrance", "You can not acces to the page", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```